# Yii: Output column from joined table in GridView

Tags: join, gridview, yii, yii2

I have a table named source_message and I want to show a column named translation from another table named message that has no model. I thought I could just do a join and output the value, but it’s not working.

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new Translations();
    $searchModel->load(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        
    $query = $searchModel->find()->select('source_message.*, message.*')->innerJoin('message', 'source_message.id = message.id');

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => new yii\data\ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]),
    ]);
}
```

And in my view I have:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'id'
        'message.translation',
    ]
]) ?>
```

All posts about that topic are about joining tables which have models. But I don’t need a model for the message table. Also I tried it with a model and it also didn’t work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Creating a model for message table is simplest and cleanest solution. There are alternatives like using `SqlDataProvider` instead of `ActiveDataProvide` but it will give you more work than what's worth in this case. There is hardly any reason for not creating a model for table.

Comment: You are not using relation in query, so you can't use `activedataProvider`  either define relation in model or use `sqldataprovider` as @MichalHynčica suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in view

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'id',
         [
          'attribute' => 'name_of_your_attribute',
          'label' => 'Your Label',
          'value' => function($model){
             return $model->name_relation->attribute_table;
           }
         ],
        'message.translation',
    ]
]) ?>
```

from your model access the relation and from the relation access the attribute, this works for hasOne relation, but you need to have the relations created inside the model

Comment: Using `'relationName.attributeName'` in columns array works fine if your relation is defined properly. You don't have to use value callback for that.